# SQLite3 Prepared Statements is getting me an error

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm getting these errors when I use SQLite3 Prepared Statements

> Warning: SQLite3::prepare(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, near ";": syntax error in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tests/11/index.php on line 14`
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function bindValue() on boolean in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tests/11/index.php on line 15

My code is:

```
$db = new SQLite3('database.sqlite', SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE);

$db->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    "user_id" INTEGER,
    "profile_photo" VARCHAR,
    "reg_date" DATETIME)');

$statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO "users" ("user_id", "profile_photo", "reg_date") VALUES (;uid, ;profile_photo, ;reg_date)');
$statement->bindValue(';uid', 12);
$statement->bindValue(';profile_photo', 'usr12-e.jpg', SQLITE3_TEXT);
$statement->bindValue(';reg_date', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: Try using `:` instead of `;`? And are you sure your quotes are right? I'm not really a SQLite user, but using string quotes for identifiers doesn't seem right?

Comment: If sqllite supports it I would make `reg_date` default value the current datetime. That will be easier to use, and write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your insert statement and your bindValue. You should use a colon (:) instead of a semicolon (;) in writing the names of prepared variables.

**Here's the correct way of doing that:**

```
$statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO "users" ("user_id", "profile_photo", "reg_date") VALUES (:uid, :profile_photo, :reg_date)');
$statement->bindValue(':uid', 12);
$statement->bindValue(':profile_photo', 'usr12-e.jpg', SQLITE3_TEXT);
$statement->bindValue(':reg_date', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$statement->execute();
```